# Recommended IPv6 prefix size for PPP to a single host?

Tags: ip, subnet, protocol-theory, ipv6, prefix

I am using PPP to create a IPv6 connection to a remote host.

What is the recommended IPv6 prefix size for a single host at the other end of the PPP connection?

- Should it be /128, because there is only a single host
- Should it be /64 to make it more like other setups and allow for the remote host to have multiple IPv6 addresses
- Something in between?

If /64 does that mean I should be allocating individual /64 allocations for each remote host on its individual PPP connection.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Comment: Not really, no. I got an answer about router->router links, when I asked about router->host links. Still hoping there is an RFC somewhere that advises on this.

Comment: Do you understand that on a network, a router _is_ a host. A router is simply a host that knows how to reach other networks? Also, other hosts, e.g. PCs, have routing tables and can even forward packets between networks. What distinction are you drawing? The ping-pong attack is mitigated by using `/127` links between two devices, and we use that for all point-to-point links.

Answer (score 4):

*[RFC 6164, Using 127-Bit IPv6 Prefixes on Inter-Router Links](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6164)* explains that `/127` networks are good for point-to-point links:

> Abstract
>
> On inter-router point-to-point links, it is useful, for security and
> other reasons, to use 127-bit IPv6 prefixes. Such a practice parallels
> the use of 31-bit prefixes in IPv4. This document specifies the
> motivation for, and usages of, 127-bit IPv6 prefix lengths on
> inter-router point-to-point links.

Comment: What if the remote peer is a host, rather than a router?

Comment: It still works. Unlike the IPv4 `/31`, which, despite having an RFC, is not supported by everything (Microsoft), everything seems to support IPv6 `/127`, even Microsoft. There are real reasons that `/127` is recommended, including reasons that could affect hosts.

Comment: I believe SLAAC can only be used on subnets with a /64 prefix. Does that mean that /127 subnets must be manually configured? Or can DHCPv6 be used?

Comment: Yes, but you always want to statically configure the addressing on your network equipment, e.g. your router. You could use DHCP or static configuration for the host. IPv6 networks smaller than `/127` can be vulnerable to ping pong attacks.